# Section Title Style

Tags: sectioning, formatting, sections-paragraphs

I have been using the default style for section and subsection titles. I want to make some adjustment when needed.

For example, right now, my titles for both a section and a subsection are appearing in bold letters. How shall I change titles for only subsections from bold to unbold? Thank you.

Comment: Please post a small, compilable document demonstrating your current layout so people do not have to start from scratch in order to help you. It matters a whole lot which document class you are using, whether you are loading any packages which affect section title formatting and whether you are loading packages which affect the fonts which are active.

Comment: Unless you add some specifics, it looks like your question can be easily answered if you search in the forum for «section format». The most frequent solution is to use the titlesec package

Comment: The `titlesec` package can easily do that.

Comment: Please close votes give the op time to react. Closing after 50 minutes is too fast, I think.

Comment: -1 You are a member for quite some time and have asked questions before. This one is very unspecific not even mentioning the document class. Please add a minimal working example to the question that shows the basic setup and hence improves your question.

Comment: Sorry about the inconvenience. I should just learn the basic about `titlesec`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\subsection` command for standard classes could be defined as

```
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
```

You can just remove `\bfseries` like

```
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\large}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
```

To make them un bold.

Another way is to use the short form:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\titleformat{\subsection}
%{\normalfont\large}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\large}
\begin{document}
  \section{Some section}
  This is some filler text.
  \subsection{Some subsection}
  This is some filler text.
\end{document}
```

Or you can also use `sectsty`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\subsectionfont{\normalfont\large}
\begin{document}
  \section{Some section}
  This is some filler text.
  \subsection{Some subsection}
  This is some filler text.
\end{document}
```

If you want to fire an ICBM on a squirrel use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
           {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
           {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
           {\normalfont\large}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \section{Some section}
  This is some filler text.
  \subsection{Some subsection}
  This is some filler text.
\end{document}
```

Here the original definition was `\normalfont\large\bfseries`